# how do i get data from a many to many intermediate table to be used in thymeleaf?

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot, thymeleaf, spring-thymeleaf

I have a table that links a sale to a product with their id's, because sales and products is a many to many relationship, and I need to use that table as I normally do with a table when using thymeleaf. For example, if I want all the data in the table 'products', I do the following:

```
        <tbody>
            <tr th:each="producto:${productos}">
                <td th:text="${producto.codigo_producto}"></td>
                <td th:text="${producto.nombre}"></td>
                <td th:text="${producto.marca}"></td>
                <td th:text="${producto.costo}"></td>
                <td th:text="${producto.cantidad_disponible}"></td>
                
            </tr>
```

```
    @GetMapping("/verproductos")
    public String verProductos(Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("productos",this.productoService.getAllProductos());
        
        return "paginaproductos";
    }
```

But in this case, I don't know how to do it because it is just the intermediate table that is automatically created with the @JoinTable annotation. How can I bring all the data from this table?.

I was trying to somehow get all from this table,just like the findAll() method , or something like that but I don't know how to access this table